# Python locally without package-manager-installer in Debian?

Tags: python, installation, debian

My package-manager has been broken now over one month and I have been unable to fix it, more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13204173/broken-debian-package-manager-how-to-deal-with-it). I am now looking for a way to circumvent this problem without the package-manager/installer. How can I use python without pkg -manager in Debian?

**Example error:** `"python -m http.server 8000 /usr/bin/python: No module named http"`

Comment: Your problem appears to be with trying to run something that you don't have, not with Python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That doesn't seem to have anything to do with a missing package manager.

The `http.server` module comes with python 3 by default.
If you're using python 2, use `SimpleHTTPServer` instead.

Comment: `"python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000"` started to work. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you want to avoid using apt, or if you don't have administrator rights, you can use `easy_install` to grab most python pakcages and store them in your home folder.  Just add `--install-dir $HOME/lib/<pythonversion>/dist-packages` and then put `export PYTHONPATH=$HOME/lib/<pythonversion>/dist-packages` in your .bashrc or similar.